# Upgrading to 2K8 Server, An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '\\networkshare'

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I moved my site off of a 2k3 server over to a 2k8 server.  The site has a virtual directory pointed to a network share which has different credentials than the one used by the site. I set the virtual directory to use the correct credentials and it can browse the share fine through explorer, but when I try to load files (images, etc) through a browser I get the following asp.net error:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error  Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file:
>   Failed to start monitoring changes to '\\networkshare'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: \\networkshare\web.config    Line: 0
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5456;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456

The network share does not have a web.config.

I tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271521/an-error-occurred-loading-a-configuration-file-failed-to-start-monitoring-chang), but that did not solve the issue and this site isn't using impersonation. Do I need to enable impersonation?  This was working correctly on win2k3.

Comment: Is the website hosted on a network share or a local drive?

Comment: local drive. the 2k8 server is a virtual machine.

Comment: Is there any actual usage of "\\networkshare" in the site?  I'm curious why it thinks it needs to access that share.  But more than likely this is a file system or share permissions issue.  I'm guessing you're coming from IIS6?

Comment: Yes, I am coming from iis 6.  The network share is a content share between multiple web servers.  I am also having system engineering look at the permissions to make sure everything is set up correctly since the error message is extremely vague.

Comment: I should also note that this wasn't an OS upgrade, rather a move from IIS6/2K3 to IIS7/2K8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so based on our comments it sounds like this is either a share permissions problem or an NTFS permissions problem (same resolution, different dialog).

In IIS6 you typically had the worker process running as `NETWORK SERVICE` and that's what you would give permissions to to access shares and files on the network.

In IIS7.5 the application pools now run under an AppPool identity, one specific to the application pool that the website is running under. This link should be helpful: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

As a quick fix (although I recommend reading up on it) though, you can go into the application pool, go to advanced properties, and set the identity back to `NETWORK SERVICE`.